# running dart project says dart:html is not available for the standalone vm

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I used Git to pull a project
I then start IntelliJ, and say:  Open Project.

The project itself looks like it has 4 modules, Lab1, Lab2, Solution2, Solution2

I open the full project.  In Lab1, i want to run to see how my web page looks, but when i say:  `Run main.dart` the error kicked back is:

```
C:\code\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --ignore-unrecognized-flags --checked --enable-vm-service:51293 --trace_service_pause_events C:\code\workspace\tw_remoting_training\codelab_01\web\main.dart
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51293
The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.
'package:remoting_training/remoting_printer.dart': error: line 20 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dart:html';
^

Process finished with exit code 254
```

Im not sure what is going on here though.  As a secondary option, i will also try to Right-Click on index.html and click: Open with > Dartium but that shows a blank page.  It shouldve done 4 async calls which printed strings to the screen.

Is there something I am missing?  Is it not running because of it being a module in a project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your Dart script imports `dart:html` or a library that imports `dart:html` you can run that script only from the Dartium browser (by adding a script tag to HTML that points the that Dart script, or if you run it through `pub build` or `dart2js` in any browser), but it can't be run from the console.

With `dart:io` it's exactly the opposite, it can't be run in the browser.

Comment: So, how a Flutter web project can be compiled to apk which imports dart:html ? Any solution?

Comment: I didn't try Flutter web yet, but I'm sure they have s way to include different implementations per build target. I could imagine that you need to build a plugin for that, but that's just a wild guess.